# Why is RMS used for P=VI (where there are no squares)?

Tags: math, theory, rms

I understand why RMS values are used for

$$P = {\bar{v^2} \over R}$$

because \$\bar{v^2}\$ would be the "MS" so to speak, and then by square rooting we get the "RMS" (\$\sqrt{\bar{v^2}}\$), which can then be squared to give \$\bar{v^2}\$, meaning the above equation is equivalent to:
$$ P_{av} = {V^2_{rms} \over R}$$

However, why are RMS values used for calculating the average power using \$P = VI\$, i.e

$$P_{av} = \bar{V}\bar{I}$$

In a textbook I see this equation for power for AC written as:

$$P_{av} = V_{rms}I_{rms}$$

Why is the mean of the square values used here when there are no squares in the equation? Surely it should just be the (non squared) average of the absolute voltage and current?

Comment: So, you do not know whay we introduce the RMS value for a voltage/current?

Comment: @G36 I understand why it is used for power formula where there is a square value, I don't understand why it is used for P=VI.

Comment: Because only  V_rms x I_rms give us average power equal to the DC power if a DC voltage is equal to V_rms and the DC current is equal to I_rms  . https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-1/measurements-ac-magnitude/

Comment: It's kind of the other way around. We use RMS *because* it makes the power work out nicely like that.

Comment: @G36 But why? For a formula with squares it obviously makes sense to take the mean of the square values. But for P = VI there are no squares. So why use the mean of the squares? Surely we should use the average of V and I, not the average of the square values of V and I?

Comment: @JShorthouse Think about what the average of an AC sinusoidal wave is (or any other waveform centered around zero). And think about whether something light a resistor ever dissipates negative power just because the direction its voltage or current has changed direction.

Comment: @JShorthouse That's not the average value of a sine wave

Comment: @DKNguyen This isn't a valid explanation, it's just a gotcha that doesn't make sense, and it doesnt explain why Vrms should be used. Obviously if we're calculating the average voltage then we should use a rectified / absolute wave, so the average voltage is \${2\over\pi}\cdot V_{peak}\$. So my question is, why don't we use this instead of the RMS?

Comment: @JShorthouse Do you know calculus?

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes I do

Comment: @JShorthouse Let me see if I can cook something up.

Comment: @JShorthouse But while I'm doing that, try simmering on how the RMS and average value being equal for for a constant value DC signal, is the exception, not the rule.

Comment: @JShorthouse But I'm already in the middle of writing mine =( lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instantaneous power is product of the instantaneous voltage \$v(t)\$ and the instantaneous \$v(t)\$ current:

$$p(t) = v(t)i(t)$$

Therefore, the average power  is the area underneath the \$v(t)i(t)\$ curve divided by time. In other words, it's the average of the instantaneous power over time. For a periodic signal, this is:

$$P_{avg} =\frac{1}{T}\int{p(t)dt}= \frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {v(t)i(t)dt}$$

These are, as far as I know, the fundamental definitions for electrical power from which all others arise. Everything else is simplifications and generalizations since our monkey brains aren't able to sit there and calculate power from a bunch of instantaneous values on the fly.

The definition of RMS for a periodic signal is:

$$RMS = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {[f(t)]^2dt}}$$

Now this is going to be an empirical example since it's just faster but hopefully it will demonstrate things.

Let's assume the following voltage and current waveforms, which covers all resistors values with any voltage waveform being applied across them:
$$v(t)=v(t)$$
$$i(t)=\frac{v(t)}{R}$$

Therefore, the average power is:
$$P_{avg} = \frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {\left( v(t) \times \frac{v(t)}{R}\right)dt} =\boxed{ \frac{1}{RT}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {[v(t)]^2dt}}$$

Now let's compare this result to what happens when you multiply the RMS of the voltage and current waveforms together.

First we take:

$$V_{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {[v(t)]^2dt}}$$

$$I_{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {[i(t)]^2dt}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {\frac{[v(t)]^2}{R^2}dt}}$$

Then multiply them together:

$$V_{RMS} \times I_{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {[v(t)]^2dt}} \ \times \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {\frac{[v(t)]^2}{R^2}dt}}$$

$$= \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {[v(t)]^2dt}} \ \times \sqrt{\frac{1}{R^2T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {[v(t)]^2dt}}$$

$$= \sqrt{\frac{1}{R^2T^2}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {[v(t)]^2dt} \ \times \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {[v(t)]^2dt}}$$

$$= \sqrt{\frac{1}{R^2T^2} \left(\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {[v(t)]^2dt} \right)^2}$$

$$\boxed{= \frac{1}{RT} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} {[v(t)]^2dt}}$$

So you can see that the calculation of power from instantaneous values is equal to the result of multiplying the RMS values together.

This can be generalized to all functions but was a lot easier to just use example functions (much stronger calculus skills are required to solve for the multiplication of those two integrals when the function inside the integral, \$v(t)\$ and \$i(t)\$ are both arbitrary. I feel that it would involve using Taylor expansions to represent the arbitrary functions which would give you something that would still be arbitrary but have enough substance to be mathematically manipulated. Either that, or representing the functions as generic fourier series which would put into a form similar to what I have done here with sine (or cosine), but with an infinite number of terms.

So I guess the answer to your question is that the squaring is there because it arises from the fundamental definition of instantaneous power, and the average power being time average of the instantaneous power.

The definition for RMS builds in the squared values into the definition, which is then used to determine \$V_{rms}\$ and \$I_{rms}\$. That is why if you go \$P_{avg}=V_{rms}I_{rms}\$ you don't need any squares since it's already accounted for.

And when you use \$P = I^2R = \frac{V^2}{R} \$ you are only ever working with instantaneous power and instantaneous current/voltages, or average power and constant DC values where the squaring has not happened yet so you must handle the squaring manually for yourself.

It just happens to be a coincidence and special case that for constant DC signals, RMS and AVG are the same, but you don't ever actually care about the average amplitude of voltage or current as far as average power is concerned. I think @Hearth put it best when he said the average of the product is not the product of the averages. It might be unintuitive to see why the squaring needs to be there, but with that quote it should be intuitive to see why just multiplying the averages doesn't work. Gotta be careful when combining averages...the average of the a bunch of averages isn't the same as the average of everything either, especially weighted averages.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write up this proof, I can see how both are equivalent now - although I haven't had the time to fully understand everything.

Comment: @JShorthouse Fixed some errors in the last couple of lines.

Answer (score 5):

In short: Using RMS values for AC power yields a simpler expression that is analogous to the expression for DC power of \$P = IV\$.

The expression for AC power, using peak values for current and voltage, is:
$$
P = \frac{1}{2} \cdot I_{pk} \cdot V_{pk}
$$

RMS values simplify this by absorbing the \$\frac{1}{2}\$ factor into the current and voltage values:

$$
\begin{align}
P &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot I_{pk} \cdot V_{pk}\\
P &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}I_{pk} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}V_{pk}\\
P &= (\frac{I_{pk}}{\sqrt{2}}) \cdot (\frac{I_{pk}}{\sqrt{2}})\\
P &= (I_{RMS}) \cdot (V_{RMS})\\
\end{align}
$$

Note that the equations above are only representing real power across a purely resistive load. Of course, with a reactive load, you'll need to work with complex power, but from your question it seems you haven't started studying that just yet.

Comment: This makes sense, but wouldn't your first formula using the peaks only work for a square wave? By my own calculations shouldn't the power of a sine be: \$P_{av} = {4\over\pi}V_pI_p\$ ?

Comment: Based on the formula \$V_{av} = {2\over\pi}\times V_p\$

Comment: Power is defined as the product of current and voltage. Instantaneous power is always the product of current and voltage at any point in time. For a resistive load, the current and voltage waveforms are in-phase, so for a sinusoidal input, the average power turns out to be simply half the product of the peak sinusoidal values. Assume \$V(t) = A \cdot sin(t)\$ and \$I(t) = B \cdot sin(t)\$. Calculate the average value of the product and see what you get. Hint: you should arrive at a value of \$\frac{AB}{2}\$.

Comment: Could you please explain where the half is coming from? The average of a half cycle sine wave is given by \${2\over\pi} \cdot Peak\$, correct? So therefore \$V_{av} = A \cdot {2\over\pi}\$ and \$I_{av} = {B}\cdot{2\over\pi}\$ meaning \$P_{av} = {4AB\over\pi}\$?

Comment: These are time-varying functions. \$P_{av}\$ is the average power **over time**. I think that is the source of your confusion. Try plugging the following string into WolframAlpha: `1/pi * integrate (A*sin(t))*(B*sin(t)) dt from 0 to pi`

Comment: I tried that equation and it checks out, but why? Maybe I'm being really dumb here but surely shouldn't the area of both the I and V  sinusoids divided by the period (your method) be the same as the average amplitude of I + the average amplitude of V (what I did)?

Comment: @JShorthouse The average of the product is not the same as the product of the averages.

Comment: @JShorthouse As explained elsewhere, no, it's not exactly the same. One extra example I can mention: the average power is taken over the entire period (not a "half cycle" of the sine wave). As you're likely aware, the average of a sine over a period is 0 (i.e. \$V_{av}\$ and \$I_{av}\$ are both equal to zero). The flaw in your logic is that you're leaving out the second half of the cycle, which would be the negative of your \$\frac{4AB}{\pi}\$ figure. This would result in a zero power, which you know can't be the case.

Comment: More succinctly: The area under the curve over a full cycle of an individual sinusoid is zero. When you multiply two in-phase sinusoids together, all of the negative peaks become positive, and the area under the resulting curve becomes positive.

Comment: @Shamtam "the average of a product is not the same as the product of averages" makes sense to me, but the idea of "the average of the voltage is 0" doesn't' sit right with me. Obviously I know it's technically true but it feels like a false explanation to me. Would a full-wave rectified sine wave not deliver the same power as an unrectified sine? Therefore if the real issue was "the average of the voltage is 0" then why not just calculate the average voltage of the rectified version of the wave? It seems that the only real issue is the problem of taking the product of averages?

Comment: @JShorthouse Sure it would. For the simple circuit of a sinusoidal source and a resistor, the reason has nothing to do with rectification. The reason is because the current is in-phase with the voltage, so during the negative peaks of each waveform, the product of two negative numbers gives a positive number. My whole point is that you can't just calculate the average of each waveform individually, you need to look at them together because "the average of a product is not the same as the product of averages."

Comment: This becomes much more important when you have reactive loads (capacitors, inductors), because then the current and voltage are _not_ in phase with each other. Remember that power involves BOTH voltage and current. It's perfectly fine to have a zero average voltage and/or current but still have positive power delivery. Equations like \$P = \frac{V^2}{R}\$ are just simplifications that work in certain cases by making certain assumptions.

Comment: @Shamtam makes perfect sense, thanks.